# Simple Residue Question

Tags: residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the residue of $g(z)=1/\sin(z)$ at the simple pole of $z=0$.

For some reason, I can't figure out how to do it since when I compute the taylor expansion of $\frac {z}{\sin(z)}$ I do not get a $z^{-1}$ term.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\sin z$. Since $0$ is a simple pole (the roots of $\sin z$ can be shown to be simple) we have that
$$
Res(f,0) = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{g'(0)}=\frac{1}{\cos 0}=1.
$$

Comment: ah yes, I forgot about L'hopital's rule. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in a neighbourhood of $z$,
$$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\frac{1}{z-\frac{z^3}{6}+o(z^3)}
=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{6}+o(z^2)}\\=
\frac{1}{z}\cdot\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+o(z^2)\right)=
\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{6}+o(z).$$
What is the residue at $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Remember the residue formula is $$Res(f,z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^k f^{(k-1)}(z),$$
where $k$ is the multiplicity of $z_0.$